# Free running ramp generator with negative maximum and minimum voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger, sawtooth-waveform

[image]

I'm currently trying to figure out how to design a free running ramp generator for a project. I'm required to use op amps for both the bootstrap sawtooth generator and the Schmitt trigger, and the required output voltage ranges from -8 to -1 V. This implies that the UTP is -1 and the LTP is -8.

I'm having a hard time understanding how the output of the bootstrap would be negative along with designing the Schmitt trigger such that both threshold voltages are also negative. Any tips? I've attached a picture of the reference circuit that they've provided, which is the only reference material provided to us.

Comment: Have you considered using a simulator and seeing how the circuit in your question performs?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the behavior should be, beginning with voltages across C1 and C2.
NB: opamp's are LF13741.

[image]

[image]

Zooming in some regions ...

Starting "block" ...

[image]

And repeating "block" ...

[image]

And here the "ideal DC cyclogram" for the hysteresis part.

[image]

And here is the "transient cyclogram" of the hysteresis part.

[image]